# Expanding a density matrix in terms of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, density-operator, majorana-fermions

In Lukasz's paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2654.pdf

He writes "consider a density matrix ρ, written as a polynomial of the 2N Majoranas cj in such a way that each cj occurs to the power 0 or 1 in each term."

How exactly does one do this? Say for example that I was dealing with a very simple example, the Kitaev chain with just one fermion, and the Hamiltonian in terms of majorana operators $c_j$ looked like:

$H_0 = i c_1 c_2$. 
And we define the fermion operators to be $a_n = (1/2)(c_{2n} + i c_{cn-1})$, $a_n^+ = (1/2)(c_{2n} - i c_{cn-1})$.

Then the ground state in terms of the original fermions is the site being unoccupied. Lets call this $ |0$>. How do I write the density matrix $|0$><$0|$ as a polynomial in c_1, c_2?